# MySQL UTF8 Windows export - Linux import

Tags: mysql, windows, linux, utf-8

I have MySQL database version 5.1.36, that came with WAMP installation. I used it for development purposes on Windows XP SP3, and it has some data in it, which is **cyrillic**, and the collation for all of those tables/columns is set to `utf8_general_ci`.

Now the time has come to move this database to pseudo-production environment, which is on Debian Lenny. Version of MySQL here is 5.0.51a.

I tried the following:

1. I exported the databse with data from *phpmyadmin* on Windows and saved the `.sql` file to be in UTF8.
2. Then, I transferred it through WinSCP (both with default and binary transfer settings) to Linux machine.
3. I created the database through command line: `mysqladmin -u root -p create nbs`
4. Finally, I tried to create tables and fill the data:

   `mysql -u root -p --default-character-set=utf8 nbs < NBS_utf8_1.sql`

However, this is where I'm getting the error, like:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ï»¿
>   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `` `history_members` (
>     `id` `` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_' at line 1

Something is messed up with encoding, I suppose... but don't know how and where. I think I read in the similar question on SO that binary mode for text transfer will only change the line breaks CRLF to LF (don't know if this is correct...). What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: It does appear that your dump file contains some extraneous characters. It is a text file so binary mode should not have been used for the upload.

Comment: Yes, when I showed it with `more` in PuTTY console, the first thing to see there was this 'ï»¿  nonsense. I have no idea how it got there, but when I transferred it with text mode, it disappeared.

Comment: However, this doesn't fix the problem, because the encoding is messed up again...

Comment: What is indicating to you that the encoding is messed up?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, but when I show the content of text-mode-transferred file with `more` cyrillic chars look like ÐœÐ°Ñ€ÐºÐ¾. It's the same situation when it is default-mode-transferred, except the very first character(s) is'ï»¿. When I open the file form SCPs editor in the case of text transfer the cyrillic looks like ÐœÐ°Ñ€ÐºÐ¾ - in the case of default transfer it looks fine, eg Ахмедовски

Comment: The problem is solved with the following modifications: 1) I forgot to set initial collation while creating the database to `utf8_general_ci` 2) I transferred the file with text mode 3) I added `SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';` to the top of sql dump.

Comment: The first few characters were probably a byte order mark: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Byte_order_mark. If so, I guess the mysql command line program didn't like them because they usually don't appear in an input stream.

Comment: yes, I saved the file to utf8 using notepad++, and it came to mind that it inserts byte ordering info, but I didn't have time to examine it in depth

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this particular case, the problem was solved with the following modifications:

1) I set initial collation while creating the target database to `utf8_general_ci`,
2) I transferred the file with text mode through WinSCP,
3) I added `SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';` to the top of sql dump.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found using PhpMyAdmin for a rough SQL import using remote shell :

```
 /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
 /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
 /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
 /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
```