# utf8 garbled when importing into mysql

Tags: mysql, utf-8

Importing UTF8-encoded data into mysql is not working for me. UTF8 characters are corrupted. For example **Nöthnagel** is displayed as **NÃ¶thnagel**

I have created a sql dump file to do the importing which contains UTF-8 encoded data. For example:

```
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES(1, 'Fred','Nöthnagel');
```

The sequence of bytes representing **ö** in the file is c3 b6 which I believe is correct, as it displays correctly in vim and in my bash shell which has these environment variables set:

```
$ env | grep -i utf
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
XTERM_LOCALE=en_US.UTF-8
```

The mysql db was created as follows:

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE mydb CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

The mysql table was created so:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (  
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    `first_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,  
    `last_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),  
    UNIQUE KEY `last_name` (`last_name`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I am importing the dump file like so:

```
 mysql -u root -psecret mydb < mydump.sql
```

Please tell me what is missing from the above.

Comment: that's a good summary, but how are you doing the final display that gives NÃ¶thnagel

Comment: Did you check your file encoding ?

Comment: Have tried to use SET NAMES statement ? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html

Comment: @PaulDixon The original data is on a django website that uses sqlite. The website is now running mysql. Only the data and the django config have changed, so it is easy to compare them

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY The encoded data for ö in the file is c3 b6. I have checked other sources to confirm that this is indeed utf8

Comment: Thank you for your question here! You saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I think it might have something to do with collation as well, but I'm not sure. In my case it certainly did, since I had to support cyrillic.
Try this, worked for me:

1. Set initial collation while creating the target database to `utf8_unicode_ci`
2. Add `SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci';` to the top of your sql file
3. Run `mysql -u root -p --default-character-set=utf8 yourDB < yourSQLfile.sql`

One more thing, in order to properly get the UTF-8 data form your database, you'll have to modify your connection string as well. For example:

`mysql.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nbs?useJvmCharsetConverters=false&useDynamicCharsetInfo=false&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=UTF-8&useEncoding=true`

Additionally, take a look at what [my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425355/mysql-utf8-windows-export-linux-import) was.

Comment: default character set worked  even for export. thx <code>#mysql db_name -p -u --default-character-set=utf8 < query.sql > result-utf8.csv</code>

Comment: Your point number 3 was enough on my setup. I will mention here a few things I noticed. The default sql dump read as ISO-8859-1 in Windows Notepad but as UTF-8 in Sublime Text. I tried 'Save with encoding: UTF-8' from Sublime and got a correct readout in Notepad, but this broke the import into MySQL using the method in this answer. However I could still ```SOURCE``` the file, but the result had the wrong encoding anyway which left me very confused. The point being that the issue lies solely in the database import, and that ```SOURCE``` doesn't care.

Comment: point #2 was enough! SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';
Thank you very much and God bless you! German is a special language.

Answer (score 18):

Use this command for import utf8 table to database :

```
mysql -u USERNAME  -pPASSWORD --default_character_set utf8  DATABASE < file.sql
```

Answer (score 13):

The problem was solved by adding this at the top of the sql file:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

Comment: Both this and `--default_character_set utf8` worked, but I think I'll stick with this one. When I use `mysqldump` instead of `phpmyadmin` to export the database, I see this setting in the dump. However, phpmyadmin doesn't have this in its dump.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. There are a number of variables that should be UTF8, not only the database, those include the client, the connection, ther server ...etc.

The solution to your problem is described in [this article](http://www.adviesenzo.nl/examples/php_mysql_charset_fix/). The described solution is portable, so it does not only work for utf8, but for all other character sets. You may need to modify it to fit your needs.